# Can native UI controls be accessed directly from Nativescript

Tags: android, ios, nativescript

Am I able to access UIKit through Nativescript or what ever the equivalent would be in Android directly from NativeScript code? For example, if I wanted to add a drop shadow to a UIView and add this view to the screen, would I be able to create a new UIView and programmatically add a drop-shadow if it's not supported in the XML and CSS implementations? I know they are supposed to have a 100% parody of the Native API's so it should be possible but just want to make sure as I'm having trouble finding examples in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have full access to native objects for both iOS and android. 
For example (taken from http://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/ios/Overview.html):

Obj-C

```
UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
// Or with the short-cut
UIView *view2 = [UIView new];
```

JS equivalent

```
var view1 = UIView.alloc().init();
// Or with the short-cut
var view2 = UIView.new();
```

Look around the runtime references in the docs as there are other examples of how do you operate with native objects for iOS/Android

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much, adding the location in the docs was really helpful.